# How to make Guard watch files in a subdirectory

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, guard

I'm trying to have Guard compile my CoffeeScript files to JS files, and then have Juicer merge and minify them. I use a `tmp` directory to store the intermediate JS files. From what I understand this should work, but it doesn't:

```
guard :coffeescript, :input => "src/coffee", :output => "tmp"

guard :shell do
    watch %r{^tmp/.+\.js$} do
        system 'juicer', 'merge', 'tmp/app.js', '-sfo', 'js/app.js'
    end
end
```

CoffeeScript files are correctly compiled into the `tmp` directory every time they are touched, but then the `shell` guard does not fire.

Launching guard with `--debug` and changing one of the JS files in `tmp` by hand, I don't get any debug line in the terminal. It seems like those files are not being monitored.

```
$ guard --debug
18:53:51 - DEBUG - Command execution: which notify-send
18:53:51 - DEBUG - Command execution: emacsclient --eval '1' 2> /dev/null || echo 'N/A'
18:53:51 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
18:53:51 - DEBUG - Command execution: hash stty
18:53:51 - DEBUG - Guard starts all plugins
18:53:51 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::CoffeeScript
18:53:51 - DEBUG - Hook :start_end executed for Guard::CoffeeScript
18:53:51 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::Shell
18:53:51 - DEBUG - Hook :start_end executed for Guard::Shell
18:53:51 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/home/tobia/my_project'
18:53:51 - DEBUG - Start interactor
[1] guard(main)>
```

^^^ if I modify the JS files in `/home/tobia/my_project/tmp` at this point, nothing happens.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.1 from Debian stable, Guard 1.8.2 and Guard-shell 0.5.1 installed with `sudo gem install`

Comment: Try to make the RegExp less restrictive, e.g. %r{tmp/.+\.js$}

Comment: Tried `%r{tmp/.+\.js}`, still nothing. Should I tell Guard to "watch" the tmp directory in some way? I just modified one of the js files by hand, and Guard doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation I realized that `tmp` is in the default [ignore](https://github.com/guard/guard#ignore) list, so this is why Guard doesn't pick up changes from the generated JavaScript files. To work around this, you can either...

#### 1. Remove `tmp` from the ignored directories list

```
ignore! /.git/

guard :coffeescript, :input => "src/coffee", :output => "tmp"

guard :shell do
  watch %r{^tmp/.+\.js$} do
    system 'juicer', 'merge', 'tmp/app.js', '-sfo', 'js/app.js'
  end
end
```

#### 2. Compile the JavaScript to a different directory

```
guard :coffeescript, :input => "src/coffee", :output => "src/js"

guard :shell do
  watch %r{^src/.+\.js$} do
    system 'juicer', 'merge', 'tmp/app.js', '-sfo', 'js/app.js'
  end
end
```